# Azure SQL database is connecting even if we give empty spaces before password

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

We have developed SQL connection wizard in MVC where a user will enter SQL Server credentials and if connection is successful, we will pull records from the DB by executing a query. Everything works fine but here we are connecting to windows azure database.

The problem is if password is "test@123" and if I provide

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test@123
```

or

```
test@123 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

from UI the connection is succeeded and pulling the records.

The code which we are using to open the connection is

```
string provider = "System.Data.SqlClient"; // for example
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);

using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
{
     string connectionstring = FormatSqlConnection(SqlViewModel); // here we format sql conneciton string
     conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
     conn.Open();
     conn.Close();
     SqlViewModel.MessageType = MessageType.Success;
     SqlViewModel.MessageText = "Connection Succeeded..";
     SqlViewModel.SqlConnectionString = connectionstring;
 }
```

The `FormatSqlConnection` method is

```
private static string FormatSqlConnection(SqlConnectionModel SqlViewModel)
{
    string connectionstring = string.Format("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password={2};Initial Catalog={3};", SqlViewModel.Server, SqlViewModel.UserName, SqlViewModel.Password, SqlViewModel.DataBase);
    return connectionstring;
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So it would be usefull to see what's happening in FormatSqlConnection method, no ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thanks for the reply.. I have updated :)

Comment: I would guess a trim() is occurring somewhere in there. Might be done automatically.  It only happens with azure connections?

Comment: @Kritner : may be you are right. but how can I solve this :( if I provide spaces in between the password it's throwing error but not for trail and leading spaces :( :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that's the way connection string are treated, if you don't add quotation marks around the value.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The basic format of a connection string includes a series of
>   keyword/value pairs separated by semicolons. The equal sign (=)
>   connects each keyword and its value. To include values that contain a
>   semicolon, single-quote character, or double-quote character, the
>   value must be enclosed in double quotation marks. If the value
>   contains both a semicolon and a double-quote character, the value can
>   be enclosed in single quotation marks. The single quotation mark is
>   also useful if the value starts with a double-quote character.
>
> Conversely, the double quotation mark can be used if the value starts
>   with a single quotation mark. If the value contains both single-quote
>   and double-quote characters, the quotation mark character used to
>   enclose the value must be doubled every time it occurs within the
>   value. **To include preceding or trailing spaces in the string value,
>   the value must be enclosed in either single quotation marks or double
>   quotation marks**. Any leading or trailing spaces around integer,
>   Boolean, or enumerated values are ignored, even if enclosed in
>   quotation marks. However, spaces within a string literal keyword or
>   value are preserved. Single or double quotation marks may be used
>   within a connection string without using delimiters (for example, Data
>   Source= my'Server or Data Source= my"Server), unless a quotation mark
>   character is the first or last character in the value.

So you may try to change your formatting to

```
 string connectionstring = string.Format("Data Source={0};User ID={1};Password='{2}';Initial Catalog={3};", SqlViewModel.Server, SqlViewModel.UserName, SqlViewModel.Password, SqlViewModel.DataBase);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, you saved my day :) :) stackoverflow rocks :) :D